# Spring Boot java configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not sure what's going on here. I've been building spring apps for years and years and feel like I've just missed something.

I have a spring boot app created through the spring initializer. I created a configuration class like this.

```
@Configuration
public class WfwwebConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public WebClient webClientBean() {
        return new WebClient(MpesaPaymentService.MPESA_HOST, MpesaPaymentService.MPESA_PORT);
    }
}
```

The goal, of course, here is to create my WebClient class myself. The problem is that spring kept running the no-argument constructor on it, which was trying to go to localhost.

So I deleted that constructor and now my spring boot app won't start because WebClient doesn't have a no-arg constructor.

So what did I miss? I have

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WfwwebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WfwwebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to turn on auto configuration and all the research I've done says it will now pick up the configuration class automatically.

I double checked my @Configuration to make sure it wasn't loading it from another library. ;)

Ideas?

Comment: You might need to add the code that uses `webClientBean`

Comment: If WebClient is the interface provided by Spring, then you should create the bean using return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080"); // substitute host and port naturally...

Answer (score 2):

I was running inside the intelliJ idea environment when I found this issue. After trying many things, I tried turning debug on in the run configuration and there was nothing helpful in the messages generated.

When I turned the setting back off and re-ran the app it started working perfectly on its own.

Please post a comment if this helps someone else. I'm curious if this was it.

Comment: Mine was an Intellij problem too.  I had to close the project, restart Intellij, and then re-open the project

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following working minimal example that will print out "Hello, StackOverflow" on start-up using a `@Configuration` producing an object of a class with no-arg constructor.

## Application.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Greeter greeter() {
        return new Greeter("StackOverflow");
    }
}
```

## AppStartupRunner.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final Greeter greeter;

    public AppStartupRunner(Greeter greeter) {
        this.greeter = greeter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        this.greeter.greet();
    }
}
```

## Greeter.java

```
package org.example;

public class Greeter {

    private final String name;

    public Greeter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the hard work. I'm humbled.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I'm doing and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the `webClientBean` bean already exists.

My case fails because my bean is repeated and the previous bean is initialized first.